# sess.run() does not run?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm a new here, studying tensorflow and encountering a problem.

```
import model_method
fittt(model_method.build(self,...),...parameters...)
```

The above is in the main.py importing model_method.py. Function **fittt** in main.py:

```
def fittt(model,...):
    model.fit(...)
```

**build()** in model_method.py:

```
def build(self,...):
    self.op_C,self.op_A = self.function_A(...)
    self.op_B = self.function_B(self.op_C,...)
```

**fit()** in model_method.py:

```
def fit(self,...):
    sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph,config=config)
    BB,AA = sess.run([self.op_B,self.op_A],feed_dict)
```

To check running process, I added pdb.set_trace() at the beginning of **function_A()** and **function_B()** in model_method.py as follows:

```
def function_A(self,...):
    pdb.set_trace()
    ......

def function_B(self,...):
    pdb.set_trace()
    ......
```

The two pdb.set_trace() only stopped when the build() called and didn't work when sess.run([self.op_B,self.op_A],feed_dict) called. So it means the sess.run() **didn't run** function_A() and function_B() actually. I wonder why and wanna know how to make the two functions work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling the `model_method.build()` function you create a computation graph. In this call every line of code is executed (hence why `pdb` stopped).

However, `tf.Session.run(...)` executes only those parts of computational graph which are necessary to compute the fetched values (`self.op_A`, `self.op_B` in your example). The function does not execute the entire `build()` function again.

Therefore the reason why `pdb.set_trace()` did not execute when you've run `sess.run(...)` is because they are not valid `Tensor` objects and hence not part of the computational graph.

**UPDATE**

Consider the following:

```
class My_Model:

  def __init__(self):
      self.np_input = np.random.normal(size=(10,2)) # 10x2

  def build(self):
      self._in = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[10, None]) # matrix 10xN
      W_exception = tf.random_normal(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[3,3]) # matrix 3x3
      W_success = tf.random_normal(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2,3]) # matrix 2x3
      self.op_exception = tf.matmul(self._in, W_exception) # [10x2] x [3x3] = ERROR
      self.op_success = tf.matmul(self._in, W_success) # [10x2] x [2x3] = [10x3]
      print('Computational Graph Built')

  def fit_success(self):
      with tf.Session() as sess:
          res = sess.run(self.op_success, feed_dict={self._in : self.np_input})
          print('Result shape: {}'.format(res.shape))

  def fit_exception(self):
      with tf.Session() as sess:
          res = sess.run(self.op_exception, feed_dict={self._in : self.np_input})
          print('Result shape: {}'.format(res.shape))
```

and then calling:

```
m = My_Model()
m.build()
#> Computational Graph Built

m.fit_success()
#> Result shape: (10, 3)

m.fit_exception()
#> InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [10,2], In[1]: [3,3]
```

So to explain what you see there. We first define the computational graph in the `build()` function. The `_in` is our input tensor; `None` means the dimension 1 is determined dynamically - that is once we provide a tensor with specified values.

Then we defined two matrices `W_exception` and `W_success` which have all dimensions specified and their values will be randomly generated.

Then we define two operations, matrix multiplication, that each returns a tensor.

We called the `build()` function and created the computational graph, `print()` function is also executed but NOT added to the graph. Nothing is computed here. In fact, it can't even be, because the values of `_in` are not specified.

Now to show, that only necessary parts required for computation are evaluated, we call the `fit_success()` function, which simply multiplies the input tensor `_in` with the `W_success` tensor (with correct dimensions). We receive a tensor with correct shape: [10x3]. Note, that we receive no error that `op_exception` cannot be computed due to mismatched dimensions. That's because we do not need it to evaluate `op_success`.

Lastly, I just show that exception is indeed thrown when we try to evaluate the `op_exception` with the same input tensor.

Comment: It is to say that pdb.set_trace() did not execute, but other operations related with self.op_A and self.op_B in function_A() and function_B() ran because they are in the graph. So did self.op_C because self.op_B needs its value. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If `op_A`, `op_B` and `op_C` are valid tensors, with valid tensor operations applied to them then it's exactly as you've written. I also expanded my original answer with a little example you may want to try to see this in effect.

Comment: It really helps! Thanks a loooooooot!!